# SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 - parameter problem

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have the following devops task in my pipeline:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'azureappsharedresources-tfssc-nonprod-dev-001'
          ServerName: $(sqlServerName).database.windows.net
          DatabaseName: 'sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
          AuthenticationType: 'aadAuthenticationIntegrated'
          deployType: SqlTask
          SqlFile: './deploy/azure-pipelines/addContainedUsers.sql'
          SqlAdditionalArguments: '-UserName func-sms-router-dev-001 -DatabaseName sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
The content of the addContainedUsers.sql file is:

:setvar UserName "func-sms-router-dev-001"
:setvar DatabaseName "sqldb-sms-router-dev-001"

USE [$(DatabaseName)];
GO
CREATE USER [$(UserName)] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '$(UserName)';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', '$(UserName)';
GO
```

Following Martin's suggestion, I also tried:

```
SqlAdditionalArguments: '/v:UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001 /v:DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
```

When the pipeline runs, I get the following output:

```
Starting: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
Version      : 1.225.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment
==============================================================================
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Temporary inline SQL file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp631B.tmp
Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "**********"  -Inputfile "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp631B.tmp" 
Sql file: D:\a\1\s\deploy\azure-pipelines\addContainedUsers.sql
Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "**********"  -Inputfile "D:\a\1\s\deploy\azure-pipelines\addContainedUsers.sql" -UserName func-sms-router-dev-001 -DatabaseName sqldb-sms-router-dev-001
##[error]Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
Finishing: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment
```

If I enable debug on the pipeline run, I can see that the arguments are passed as expected:

```
##[debug]INPUT_SQLADDITIONALARGUMENTS: '-UserName func-sms-router-dev-001 -DatabaseName sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
```

I've raised the same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/18851)

Comment: Does `/v:UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001 /v:DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001` work? This is the expected form for passing SQL Cmd variables when doing a dacpac operation. I'm not sure if SQL Package is involved for `deployType: SqlTask` though

Comment: Looks like this Q has an example of passing variables to Invoke-Sqlcmd 
 via Powershell https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/208517/3690

Comment: Note the error is parameter _set_. That combination of parameters is not valid. Likely you shouldn't be using a user name if you are using `aadAuthenticationIntegrated` . Based on your question and answer below, there is some confusion about authentication types. What kind of security principal is `func-sms-router-dev-001`?

Comment: Typically in this task you use service principal auth and grant the Azure DevOps service connection/service principal required access to the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can see the 4 variations I tried:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'azureappsharedresources-tfssc-nonprod-dev-001'
          ServerName: $(sqlServerName).database.windows.net
          DatabaseName: 'sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
          AuthenticationType: 'aadAuthenticationIntegrated'
          deployType: SqlTask
          SqlFile: './deploy/azure-pipelines/addContainedUsers.sql'
          # SqlAdditionalArguments: '-UserName func-sms-router-dev-001 -DatabaseName sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
          # SqlAdditionalArguments: '/v:UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001 /v:DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
          # SqlAdditionalArguments: 'UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001 DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
          SqlAdditionalArguments: '-Variable UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001, DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'
```

It seems like *SqlAdditionalArguments: '-Variable UserName=func-sms-router-dev-001, DatabaseName=sqldb-sms-router-dev-001'* worked since I now get a different error:

```
##[error]Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated)
```

I guess that's progress.

Comment: The error implies that it's trying to connect with AD (Active Directory) auth or federated authentication, not AAD (Azure Active Directory) auth

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid but any ideas why? it seems like I've supplied the correct param value for AuthenticationType. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines#inputs